# Getting Issues when I build prod in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I try to run the `ng build --prod` command, my application

[image]

But if I run the `ng build` command I have no problems:

This occurred after deploying the 'ngx-bootstrap-product-tour' package.

My application settings:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "json-typescript-mapper": "^1.1.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "ng2-go-top-button": "^6.0.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap-product-tour": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^11.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  }
}

{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"] 
    },
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: English please !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an international site for IT people to communicate, so English is a standard here.

Comment: I have translated the query for the OP. It seems the problem is with `ngx-bootstrap` which is being used.

Comment: @Shan-Desai [Please don't translate posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680). The OP must do that themselves to show that they understand English enough to understand the answers as well.

Comment: @JJJ noted. will take care next time.

Comment: Si solo hablas español, puedes utilizar este sitio web: https://es.stackoverflow.com/